# Angular value provider not working

Tags: angularjs, code-injection, inject, provider

I'm injecting the value provider into my controller and I get an object, but when I try to read that object, by using `.toString()`, `String()`, or any other method, I only get `[Object object]` on the browser or the terminal.  Did I miss something?

```js
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp", [
            'ngRoute'
        ]);
})();

(function () {
    angular.module("myApp").constant('myValue', 3)
})();

(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller('AllCtrl', ['myValue', setHome]);

    function setHome(myValue) {

        console.log("Value: " + myValue);

    }

})();
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/7WQ3bz5Ao3fgT2CNvkRx?p=preview. Post a complete example, in a plunkr, reproducing the issue

Comment: Where is the object coming from that you want to pass through? Is it from a templating engine like Razor, or ejs? If so, you need to do the `raw` format of the object. In Razor, for example, it's `.value("myValue", @Html.Raw([JSON serialized model]))`. In ejs it would be `.value("myValue", <%- [JSON serialized object] %>)`

Comment: This is the Plunker i created

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/K613VK6pme4rCi7LU8Ut?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing an object from a templating engine like Razor, or ejs, you need to use the raw format of the object.

In Razor, for example, it's `.value("myValue", @Html.Raw([JSON serialized model]))`.

In ejs it would be `.value("myValue", <%- [JSON serialized object] %>)`

```
// *some .js file*
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp", [
            'ngRoute'
        ]);
})();

// *in your .ejs file*
(function () {
    // for ejs
    angular.module("myApp").constant('myValue', <%- jsonObject %>);
    // for Razor
    angular.module("myApp").constant('myValue', @Html.Raw(jsonObject));
})();

// *in another .js file*
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller('AllCtrl', ['myValue', setHome]);

    function setHome(myValue) {

        console.log("Value: " + myValue);

    }

})();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the value in the controller and not necessarily use it on my ejs template.  Sorry, my current project is big, i have all my business logic on my controllers and I'm looking for a way to minimize them by using factories, values, services, etc.

Comment: @wjr That's exactly what my answer does... You take the object from ejs and inject it into your angular controller. Did you try this?

Comment: I'm trying to use the value/constant in a controller without sending it to my template.  In other words, calling values or functions from the value or constant providers to my controllers.  Is that possible?  So far, I'm using $rootScope to use values across the project, but I didn't know if it was possible to do using providers.  Hopefully I explained it better, thank you again!

Comment: @wjr So are you trying to get values shared among multiple controllers, or are you trying to inject values across multiple modules?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get values and functions shared among multiple controllers.

Comment: @wjr You can always issue an ajax request to get your object outside of your controller that calls `angular.module("myApp").constant("myValue", myObject)` inside of the callback function. Then, once you inject a value into a module, it will be available to all controllers on that module, you just simply need to list it as a dependency. Would that solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi guys, does anyone know if there is a size limit to `myObject` in `.value("myValue", myObject)`? I am injecting my JSON via Razor, and most of the time I don't have any problems, but when the object is very large I get an out of memory exception.

Comment: @kennypowers How are you json encoding `myObject`? I have run into size issues with `Json.Encode()` and have had to use the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` instead.

Comment: @mhodges Thanks for your response `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` is what I am using. There are only a few instances -- when thousands of results are returned -- that the exception occurs. I think we are going to do server-side pagination to resolve.

Comment: @kennypowers Ah, yes, we deal with 4-500 results at the most, so the Newtonsoft serialize still works for us. It's good to know, though, that there are still size limitations. I agree that server-side pagination would do the trick. The other thing you could do is split your results into a few smaller groups, serialize the groups, and then concatenate them back together in JavaScript. It's an option.